# Cassandra standard deviation

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter, cassandra-cli

In opscenter have parameter stdev metrics but do not work for the version of Cassandra 3.0.1.  [opscenter screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTqcv.jpg)
How to look at Cassandra stdev?

Comment: Stddeviation of CPU usage?

Comment: No, Data Size  Stddeviation

Answer (score 1):

The current 5.2.x versions of OpsCenter does not support Cassandra 3.0. But the standard deviation in the data sizes is literally the standard deviation of the data load (The live disk space used by all tables on a node) metric across all the nodes using the two pass direct algorithm, not welfords or sum of sqs.

Comment: Thanks for answering. When will the new version Opscenter?

Comment: Release date isn't out yet